# Non portable pointer conversion in c (RB tree program)

Tags: c, turbo-c

**Hi friends**,
I had issue with pointer conversion in c.

**Here is my screen shot**
*Error while complied*
[image]

*function Code*
[image]

**Code**

*structure :*

```
struct node {   
int data;   
char color[5];  
struct node *p,*left,*right; 
}*temp,*root,*T2,*ptemp,*g,*u,*n,*x,*y,*z,*disp;
```

*Function:*

```
int uncle(struct node *temp)
 {  if(temp->p->p!=NULL)    
{       if(temp->p->p->left==temp->p)           return temp->p->p->right;       
else            return temp->p->p->left;    
}   
return 0; 
}
```

*Pointer assigning location :*

```
int insert_case3(struct node *n) 
{   struct node *u=uncle(n);
    if  (u!=NULL && strcmp(u->color,"Red")==0)  
{       strcpy(n->p->color,"Black");
        strcpy(u->color,"Black");   
    g=grandparent(n);       
strcpy(g->color,"Red");
        insert_case1(g);        
printf("Insert case 3 Success");    
}   
else    {       insert_case4(n);
        printf("Insert case 3 fail"); 
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

I don't know how to solve this error ☺️
Thanks for your time to read this question!

Comment: Change the definition of uncle to return `struct node *`

Comment: It's pretty clear, you are attempting to assign `struct node  *u = uncle (n)`. That won't work because `int uncle(struct node *temp)`. So you are essentially attempting `struct node *u = int` -- thus your error.

Comment: But still I had issue

Answer (score 2):

Because you are returning `int` instead of `struct node *` from your function `uncle`.

`int uncle(struct node *temp)`

needs to be

`struct node *uncle(struct node *temp)`

You can return `0` from these due to the magic of `0` but `NULL` is more traditional.

Apply the same principle to other functions too.

Also, your `color` member is not big enough for `"Black"` + a terminator.  It needs to be at least 6, possibly more if you want "purple" or "yellow".

Comment: Could you send sample return type of struct node ? ☺️

Comment: Type mismatch in redeclaration of 'Uncle'